# protractor: undefined: Stacktrace

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying out angular js tests based upon protractor. the stacktrace i have at the moment is

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.0.150:51197/wd/hub
F

Failures:

  1) E2E: The Dashboard : Main Page should have a working dashboard
   Message:
     timeout: timed out after 5000 msec waiting for spec to complete
   Stacktrace:
     undefined

Finished in 5.659 seconds
1 test, 1 assertion, 1 failure
```

Shutting down selenium standalone server.
here is my spec.js

```
describe('E2E: Open Login Page', function() {
  var driver = browser.driver;
  driver.get('http://localhost:8080/accounts/login/?next=/dashboard/')
  driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("user");
  driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys('password');
  //driver.findElement(By.xpath("\\button[]")
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(), 'Login')]")).click();
});

describe('E2E: The Dashboard', function() {
  var ptor = protractor.getInstance();

  describe(': Main Page', function() {
    it('should have a working dashboard', function() {
      ptor.get('/dashboard/#/');
      expect(ptor.getTitle()).toContain('Dashboard');
    })
  })
});
```

What am i doing wrong?? any help in this regard would be appreciated

Comment: did you add some trace to identify the blocking instructions ?

Comment: "When Jasmine cancels a test, it doesn't have a stack trace, it's just a timeout." as per this https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are running your application `http://localhost:8080`. Protractor does not spin up your application server, only the selenium server.

**If** you have to do this all in a single session you can run a command like this:

```
nohup bash -c "RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails s &";
```

To start your server (in this case a rails test server) and append the output to nohup.out. You can then run your command to start your protractor tests. I'd recommend inserting a sleep after that command to give your application server enough time to stand up before the protractor tests start executing.